# Visa etc. for Chinese grandmother to re-visit the US?

Tags: visas

My mother-in-law has visited us in the USA twice before from the PRC.  I've heard that it's easier to arrange a visit *again*. Is there a way to arrange for a visit where she won't have to go through an interview (which itself would require her to travel) or me to generate reams of paperwork including bank statements and whatnot?

I'm a 3rd (or more) generation US citizen.  My wife has recently become a naturalized citizen.  Since her last visit, Mother-in-law has been widowed, so she would be traveling alone. She's also quite elderly.

What paperwork do I need to look for?  Any recent advice from someone in the same situation?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible (mandatory even) for individuals who [meet several conditions](http://beijing.usembassy-china.org.cn/niv_renewal.html) to apply without the interview, though you'll still need to put all the usual paperwork together for the application. If she meets the conditions, she can drop off the documents at a bank branch and receive a visa without having to appear for an interview. Otherwise, the interview is, unfortunately, required.

The good news is that, thanks to an agreement a few years ago between the US and China, I understand there's a good chance she'll be issued a [10-year multiple entry](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/us-china-agree-to-extend-visas.html) visa now. This will give her a visa that she can use for multiple trips within a 10-year period without needing to reapply.